# What could be wrong with this leaf blower?

Tags: tools, tool-maintenance, repair

A little over a year ago, after complaining about the amount of cord I had to use with our electric leaf blower I was gifted an inexpensive gas blower. A [Ryobi 150 mph 400 CFM Gas Blower Vac](http://www.homedepot.com/Outdoors-Outdoor-Power-Equipment-Leaf-Blowers/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbxav/R-100390020/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051) from home depot to be precise. It probably wouldn't have been the one I would've chose, but hey. Complaining about gifts is never a good idea.

I mixed up some gas for the two stroke engine, but admittedly I did eyeball it. It started right up, and worked great. I used it for the next 30 minutes or so until it ran out of gas. At this point I needed to buy some new gas. I mixed up this next batch very carefully, and about two weeks later I went to use it again. It would not start, didn't start. Its a year later and If I was going to return it I should've done it months ago.

I'd like to get it started, but have little experience with trouble shooting small engines. I am a computer programmer, not a lawn care specialist. But, I'd love to learn. And I do have an internet connection. I am a bit stumped. Where should I begin. What could be wrong?

***note:*** looking at the reviews online this 'not starting' or tough to start seems to be a common problem.

Comment: Did you follow the starting procedure to the letter?

Comment: @The Evil Greebo Yep, sure did.

Comment: Could be neighbors put sugar in your gas. (I have no love for leaf blowers)

Comment: I don't have any experience of leaf blowers and chainsaws, but our lawnmower would need priming every time I used it. If your leaf blower is cheap, perhaps it doesn't have a priming pump, and you're expected to fill it every time you use it? If it works and then doesn't a few weeks later as a rule, it does seem fuel or lubricant (eg. poor seals resulting in wet spark plugs?) is the problem.

Comment: FWIW, I see that this engine does have a primer pump.

Comment: It's not a rake.

Comment: yeah, rakes work great on sidewalks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've done on my two-stroke chainsaw when it has refused to start:

- Remove and replace spark plug; check the gap.
- Remove and clean [with an air compressor] or replace air filter. (I just blow it out, I haven't yet replaced the filter.)
- If you see gunk when you're removing these parts, clean it up. (Because of all of the sawdust and bar oil, the chainsaw accumulates a lot of gunk. I don't know how dirty your leaf blower will get.)

These are *very* easy steps -- I'm usually a complete failure at engine/machine repair and even *I* can do these without ending up with a pile of parts that I have to bring my friendly local mechanic for reassembly. For tools, you'll need a spark plug (deep) socket, an air compressor with a blower fitting, and maybe a screwdriver to open the engine case.

I've also seen replacing the fuel filter as a suggestion, but haven't needed to do this yet. The steps above always get it restarted.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer, but it did not solve my problem. I really think the piece of equipment is just cheap junk. Thanks for the help.